# Как отловить текст из отправленной команды пользователем telebot?

Tags: python, telebot, telegram

### столкнулся с данной проблемой и никак не могу понять как ее решить

Работал с командой /set_caption бот принимает текст и регистрирует его в бд. Но есть два варианта использования этой команды

В первом варианте как видите бот отлавливает текст и отправляет в бд

> ````
> from plugins.admin import * 
> from database.database import *
>
> @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])  
> def add_capt(message):
>     if message.text == '/set_caption':
>         msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "sᴇɴᴅ ᴀ ᴄᴀᴘᴛɪᴏɴ  ᴛᴏ  > > >sᴀᴠᴇᴅ\n\nᴇx:- /set_caption File Name")
>         bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, catch_capt)
>
> def catch_capt(message):
>     user_id = message.from_user.id
>     msg = message.text
>     caption = str(msg).replace('/set_caption', '')
>     set_caption(user_id=user_id, caption=caption)
>     bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "ᴄᴜsᴛᴏᴍ  ᴄᴀᴘᴛɪᴏɴ sᴀᴠᴇᴅ  sᴜᴄᴄᴇssғᴜʟʟʏ☑️")```
> ````

А во втором он должен отавливать текст из самой команды /set_caption {ТЕКСТ ЮЗЕРА}

> ````
>     # if message.text == f'/set_caption {message.text}':
>     #     user_id = message.from_user.id
>     #     msg = message.text
>     #     caption = str(msg).replace('/set_caption', '')
>     #     set_caption(user_id=user_id, caption=caption)
>     #     bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "ᴄᴜsᴛᴏᴍ  ᴄᴀᴘᴛɪᴏɴ sᴀᴠᴇᴅ  sᴜᴄᴄᴇssғᴜʟʟʏ☑️") ```
> ````

Пытался сделать вот так, но ничего не получалось, так-же хотел провернуть через @bot.message_handler(commands['/set_caption']), но тоже не увенчалось успехом

Прошу помогите, буду очень рад. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: ткните пальцем, где у вас бот "отправляет в бд"

Comment: set_caption(user_id=user_id, caption=caption)
 bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "ᴄᴜsᴛᴏᴍ  ᴄᴀᴘᴛɪᴏɴ sᴀᴠᴇᴅ  sᴜᴄᴄᴇssғᴜʟʟʏ☑️") функция set_caption записана в отдельном файле который я импортировал

Comment: попробуйте не `@bot.message_handler`, а `@dp.message_handler`?

Answer (score 0):

```
from plugins.admin import *
from database.database import *
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('database/renamer_db.db', check_same_thread=False)
cursor = conn.cursor()

@bot.message_handler(commands=['set_caption'])
def set_capt(message):
    if message.text == "/set_caption":
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "sᴇɴᴅ ᴀ ᴄᴀᴘᴛɪᴏɴ  ᴛᴏ  sᴀᴠᴇᴅ\n\nᴇx:- /set_caption File Name")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, catch_capt)
    else:
        user_id = message.from_user.id
        msg = message.text
        caption = str(msg).replace('/set_caption', '')
        set_caption(user_id=user_id, caption=caption)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "ᴄᴜsᴛᴏᴍ  ᴄᴀᴘᴛɪᴏɴ sᴀᴠᴇᴅ  sᴜᴄᴄᴇssғᴜʟʟʏ☑️")

def catch_capt(message):
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    msg = message.text
    caption = str(msg).replace('/set_caption', '')
    set_caption(user_id=user_id, caption=caption)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "ᴄᴜsᴛᴏᴍ  ᴄᴀᴘᴛɪᴏɴ sᴀᴠᴇᴅ  sᴜᴄᴄᴇssғᴜʟʟʏ☑️")
```